# Display info when no input in react input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, input, conditional-statements

I want to create an input field in React.

It basically should display the entered input real-time (managed this part).
However, it also should display a message "no data provided!" when nothing was entered.

My if statement isn't working? Why?

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

class Exercise1 extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            firstName:""
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange (event) {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        })
    }

    render() {
        let display
        if(this.state.firstname != "") {
            display=this.state.firstName
        } else {
            display="no data provided!"
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <form>Input: 
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="firstName" 
                        placeholder = "no data provided!"
                        value={this.state.firstName}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                </form>

                <h1>{display}</h1>              
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default Exercise1
```

PS: please stick with your answer as much as possible to the code above since I am a beginner and can't follow too different approaches.

Comment: Change else to else if( this.state.firstname === null), maybe it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo here. Your state variable is `firstName` (with capital N), but you are trying to check condition with `firstname` (with small n). You should do this,

```
if(this.state.firstName != "") {
    display = this.state.firstName
} else {
    display = "no data provided!"
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-b2ekmr)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use your if like this

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

class Exercise1 extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            firstName:""
        }
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { firstName } = this.state
        return (
            <div>
                <form>Input: 
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="firstName" 
                        placeholder = "no data provided!"
                        value={this.state.firstName}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                </form>

                <h1>{firstName ? firstName : "no data provided!"}</h1>              
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default Exercise1
```

Comment: Probably works, but I go with mine which - turns out - only had a typo